# How Can I pass parameters to another initial page when a state is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to check the camera and microphone permission at the beginning, and pass the permission status to permiss page if permissions are not granted.

here is the app.tsx

```
import AppNavigation from './navigation/appNavigation';

function App() {
  return AppNavigation();
}

export default App;
```

the navigations:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import NotImplementScreen from '../screens/NotImplementScreen';
import PermissionsPage from '../screens/Permission';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {request, check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
// prettier-ignore
export default function AppNavigation() {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState("unavailable");
  const [microphonePermission, setMicrophonePermission] = useState("unavailable");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios')
    {
      check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA).then((result) => {setCameraPermission(result);});
      check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE).then((result) => {setMicrophonePermission(result);});
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'android')
    {
      check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA).then((result) => {setCameraPermission(result);});
      check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.RECORD_AUDIO).then((result) => {setMicrophonePermission(result);});
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(
    `Re-rendering Navigator. Camera: ${cameraPermission} | Microphone: ${microphonePermission}`,
  );

  if (cameraPermission == null || microphonePermission == null) {
    // still loading
    return null;
  }

  const showPermissionsPage = cameraPermission != "granted" || microphonePermission != "granted";

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={showPermissionsPage ? 'Permissions' : 'Home'} >
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          name="Not Implement"
          component={NotImplementScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          name="Permissions"
          component={PermissionsPage}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

that means when cameraPermission and microphonePermission changed , I want to pass these two permissions to **PermissionsPage**

if I use **initialParams** like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          name="Permissions"
          component={PermissionsPage}
initialParams={{cameraPermissionStatus:cameraPermission}}
        />
```

the parameter only valid when screen is initialized, but at that time cameraPermission is not ready.
how can I pass cameraPermission to PermissionsPage when it changed

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [useFocus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook to check the permission state when the user return fom settings screen to your app.
2. To spread the value across the app you can use [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext)

Answer (score 0):

You may pass params like so

```js
<Stack.Screen
  options={{headerShown: false}}
  name="Permissions"
  children={() => <PermissionsPage cameraPermissionStatus={cameraPermission} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`initialRouteName` is only applied when the navigator is loaded.

> The name of the route to render on first load of the navigator.

Use conditional rendering instead, something like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {showPermissionsPage ? (
      <Stack.Screen name="Permissions" component={PermissionsScreen} />
    ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
    <Stack.Screen name="Other" component={OtherScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

See [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to conditionally wait until the permissions are resolved, then you probably don't want to start with non-null initial state values since that is what your code checks for to stay in the "loading" condition.

Update the initial `cameraPermission` and `microphonePermission` from `"unavailable"` to undefined, and when the permission checks settle, update the states to a defined value. Use a `catch` block to initialize the states in the case of any rejected promises, and if the platform is neither iOS or Android, use some default check to set that the permissions are `"unavailable"` as well.

You can then pass the initial parameters to the `"Permissions"` screen once the states have completed "loading" and the stack navigator is finally mounted and rendered.

Example:

```
export default function AppNavigation() {
  const [
    cameraPermission,
    setCameraPermission
  ] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [
    microphonePermission,
    setMicrophonePermission
  ] = useState<string | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    switch(Platform.OS) {
      case 'ios':
        check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA)
          .then(setCameraPermission)
          .catch(() => setCameraPermission("unavailable"));
        check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE)
          .then(setMicrophonePermission)
          .catch(() => setMicrophonePermission("unavailable"));
        return;

      case 'android':
        check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA)
          .then(setCameraPermission)
          .catch(() => setCameraPermission("unavailable"));
        check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.MICROPHONE)
          .then(setMicrophonePermission)
          .catch(() => setMicrophonePermission("unavailable"));
        return;

      default:
        setCameraPermission("unavailable");
        setMicrophonePermission("unavailable");
    }
  }, []);

  if (!cameraPermission || !microphonePermission) {
    // still loading
    return null;
  }

  const showPermissionsPage = cameraPermission !== "granted" || 
    microphonePermission !== "granted";

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={showPermissionsPage ? 'Permissions' : 'Home'}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Not Implement"
          component={NotImplementScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Permissions"
          component={PermissionsPage}
          initialParams={{ cameraPermissionStatus: cameraPermission }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finaly, I use Context to solve my problem.

define a context:

```
import React from 'react';

export const PermissionContext = React.createContext();
```

then import in appnavigation page and use it like this:

```
const permissionContext = useMemo(()=>{return {cameraPermission,microphonePermission};},[cameraPermission,microphonePermission]);

<PermissionContext.Provider value={permissionContext}>
<Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          name="Permissions"
          component={PermissionsPage}
        />
</PermissionContext.Provider/>
```

and in permissionspage :

```
const {cameraPermission,microphonePermission} = React.useContext(PermissionContext);

 useEffect(() => {
   setCameraPermission(cameraPermission);
   setMicrophonePermission(microphonePermission);
  }, [cameraPermission, microphonePermission]);
```

Thanks all for your help!